# Translate to razor Syntax from MVC 2.0 code

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2, razor, migration

I am trying to convert the popular asp.net MVC 2.0 solr.net sample app code to Razor syntax. I am not able to understand the last line ... Kindly help

```
 <% Html.Repeat(new[] { 5, 10, 20 }, ps => { %>
            <% if (ps == Model.Search.PageSize) { %>
            <span><%= ps%></span>
            <% } else { %>
            <a href="@Url.SetParameters(new {pagesize = ps, page = 1})">@ps</a>
            <% } %>
  <% }, () => { %> | <% }); %>
```

[update]
**Source for Html.Repeat extension**

[HtmlHelperRepeatExtensions.cs](https://github.com/paulbouwer/SolrNet/blob/master/SampleSolrApp/Helpers/HtmlHelperRepeatExtensions.cs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this to work you will have to modify the `Html.Repeat` extension method to take advantage of [Templated Razor Delegates](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/02/27/templated-razor-delegates.aspx) as illustrated by Phil Haack. And then:

```
@{Html.Repeat(
    new[] { 5, 10, 20 }, 
    @<text>
        @if (item == Model.Search.PageSize)
        {
            <span>@item</span>
        }
        else
        {
            <a href="@Url.SetParameters(new { pagesize = item, page = 1 })">
                @item
            </a>
        }
    </text>,
    @<text>|</text>
);}
```

---

UPDATE:

According to your updated question you seem to be using a custom HTML helper but as I stated in my answer you need to updated this helper to use the Templated Razor Delegates syntax if you want it to work. Here's for example how it might look:

```
public static class HtmlHelperRepeatExtensions
{
    public static void Repeat<T>(
        this HtmlHelper html,
        IEnumerable<T> items,
        Func<T, HelperResult> render,
        Func<dynamic, HelperResult> separator
    )
    {
        bool first = true;
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            if (first)
            {
                first = false;
            }
            else
            {
                separator(item).WriteTo(html.ViewContext.Writer);
            }

            render(item).WriteTo(html.ViewContext.Writer);
        }
    }
}
```

or if you want to have the helper method directly return a HelperResult so that you don't need to use the brackets when calling it:

```
public static class HtmlHelperRepeatExtensions
{
    public static HelperResult Repeat<T>(
        this HtmlHelper html,
        IEnumerable<T> items,
        Func<T, HelperResult> render,
        Func<dynamic, HelperResult> separator
    )
    {
        return new HelperResult(writer =>
        {
            bool first = true;
            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                if (first)
                    first = false;
                else
                    separator(item).WriteTo(writer);
                render(item).WriteTo(writer);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

and then inside your view:

```
@Html.Repeat(
    new[] { 5, 10, 20 }, 
    @<text>
        @if (item == Model.Search.PageSize)
        {
            <span>@item</span>
        }
        else
        {
            <a href="@Url.SetParameters(new { pagesize = item, page = 1 })">
                @item
            </a>
        }
    </text>,
    @<text>|</text>
)
```

Comment: Thanks Darin for the nice example, but still I am not able to fix it. I have added the source code link for @html.Repeat extension method

Comment: You don't seem to have updated the `Repeat` helper to use the Templated Razor Delegates syntax as I explicitly stated in my question. That's the reason it doesn't work. Let me update my answer to illustrate with an example the necessary changes you need to do.

Comment: Thanks again Darin .. actually I was not able to relate "Action" objects mentioned in the parameter

Answer (score 0):

Possibly something like:

```cs
}, () => { <text>|</text> });
```

Comment: lamda expressions don't work in Razor currently. I think Razor vNext supports it though.