# Embed HTML output within razor function-call?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm looking at [this](http://bugsquash.blogspot.co.il/2009/02/repeater-with-separator-for-aspnet-mvc.html) page, which contains the following razor extension:

```
public static void Repeat<T>(this HtmlHelper html, IEnumerable<T> items, Action<T> render, Action separator)
```

Here is the usage example from that page:

```
<% Html.Repeat(Model.Products, p => { %> 
    <div><%= p.Id%></div>
    <div><%= p.Name%></div>
<%}, () => { %> 
    <br /> <%-- separator --%>
<% }); %>
```

I can't figure out how to translate the above snippet to razor code, how do I embed Html output in a function-call code-block?

I tried this:

```
@Html.Repeat(
  items: Model.Nodes,
  render: node => @: <a href='@node.Title'>@node.Url<a />
, separator: () => @:|
)
```

But I get the following exception:

> CS0201: Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

I updated the `Repeat` function as answered bellow, now my razor code looks like the following:

```
@{
  Html.Repeat(
    items: Model.Nodes,
    template: @<text><a href="@item.Url">@item.Title</a></text>,
    separator:  @<text> | </text>);
}
```

But in fact no item is being rendered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following extension method allows you to have the helper method to directly return a HelperResult so that you don't need to use the brackets when calling it:

```
public static class HtmlHelperRepeatExtensions
{
    public static HelperResult Repeat<T>(
        this HtmlHelper html,
        IEnumerable<T> items,
        Func<T, HelperResult> render,
        Func<dynamic, HelperResult> separator
    )
    {
        return new HelperResult(writer =>
        {
            bool first = true;
            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                if (first)
                    first = false;
                else
                    separator(item).WriteTo(writer);
                render(item).WriteTo(writer);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

and then inside your view:

```
@Html.Repeat(
    new[] { 5, 10, 20 }, 
    @<text>
        @if (item == Model.Search.PageSize)
        {
            <span>@item</span>
        }
        else
        {
            <a href="@Url.SetParameters(new { pagesize = item, page = 1 })">
                @item
            </a>
        }
    </text>,
    @<text>|</text>
)
```

Please note, I took the code above from the following link. For details, please refer to the following post.

[Translate to razor Syntax from MVC 2.0 code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11036496/translate-to-razor-syntax-from-mvc-2-0-code)

Comment: CS1593: Delegate 'System.Action' does not take 1 arguments

Comment: I change the first `@<text>` to `(i)=> @<text>`, but then I get this error: `CS0201: Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement`.

Comment: you wouldn't want to do that, you would wrap it in a braces like this i=> @{ <text> .....  },

Comment: Nope. `Keyword, identifier, or string expected after verbatim specifier: @`, here's my code: `(node) => @{ <text><a href="@node.Url">@node.Title</a></text> },`.

Comment: I replaced the `Repeat` function with the one you provided above, but it doesn't render any items. I placed a breakpoint in the lambda expression but the debugger won't stop there. Anyway, I didn't understand how do I pass the parameter? It's supposed to be a lambda expression that takes 1 argument of type `T`, isn't it? I could clearly see there were 7 items as passed argument in the items param?

Comment: The problem with you code is your are wrapping the helper with @{ } instead of calling @Html.Repeat directly. Remove the curly brace and it should give you what you want

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@Html.Repeat(
  items: Model.Nodes,
  render: node => ((Func<dynamic, object>)(@<a href='@node.Title'>@node.Url<a />)).Invoke(node),
  separator: node => ((Func<dynamic, object>)(@<text>|</text>)).Invoke(node)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Html.Repeat extensions return type is void. aspx engine renderer handle it different way. So the extension method required little change.

```
 @Html.Repeat(p.Categories, cat => {
                    return "<a href=" + Url.SetFacet("cat", cat) + ">" + cat + "</a>";
                 }, ",")
```

The method definition

```
    public static MvcHtmlString Repeat<T>(this HtmlHelper html, IEnumerable<T> items, Func<T, string> content, string separator)
    {
        if (items == null)
            items = Enumerable.Empty<T>();
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(string.Join(separator, items.Select(content).ToArray()));
    }
```