# Translate MVC3 Razor to MVC2

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I already develop web application using mvc3 razor but my client want me to use mvc2.
my problem is i develop helper that can pass html code to c# code and append it to my function.

Here is my sample helper.

```
public class SampleHelper
{
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public SampleHelper Content(Func<object, HelperResult> template)
    {
        string html = template.Invoke(null).ToHtmlString();
        this.Content = html;
        return this;
    }
    public MvcHtmlString Render()
    {
        string html = @"<div class='content'>" + this.Content + "</div>";
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(html);
    }
}
```

this is the way i use it in View Html

```
@SampleHelper.Create().Content(@<text>
    <input id='sample' type='button' value='test button inside div' />
</text>).Render()
```

Can anyone help me to convert this to MVC2.
I tried this link but no luck.
[Translate to razor Syntax from MVC 2.0 code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11036496/translate-to-razor-syntax-from-mvc-2-0-code)

Answer (score 1):

This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676746/custom-html-helpers-create-helper-with-using-statement-support) gives an example of how such wrapping extensions can be implemented. In your case you might want something like this as `DisposableHelper` implementation:

```
public static class DisposableExtensions
{
    public static IDisposable SampleHelper(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper)
    {
        string startTag = @"<div class='content'>";
        string endTag = "</div>";
        return new DisposableHelper(
            () => htmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Response.Write(startTag),
            () => htmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Response.Write(endTag)
        );
    }
}
```

Then you can use it just like `BeginForm` method:

```
@using (Html.SampleHelper()){
    <input id='sample' type='button' value='test button inside div' />
}
```

Comment: Thank you. i got you idea here.

Comment: @Maynard, you are welcome. Let me know if more info is needed